# Dynamic extends class in a typescript annotation

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, decorator

Suppose I have 2 class, A and B.
I want to create a typescript annotation that does the same thing that extends class dynamically.
I cannot use extends because the class A is only known at runtime.So in the result I want     class A extends B {}
But with A dynamic.

I have tried to create an annotation :

```
function extendsWithB(target) {
  //do something to extends the target with B class
  return target;
}
```

This could be use like that:

```
 @extendsWithB
   Class A {}
```

Any idea about what should I put in my annotation?

Edit: this question is purely theorical. I don't want to try this in production or something else.

Comment: You cannot extend the class in the runtime because the TypeScript is _not existing_ at the runtime. Instead in the produced JavaScript (at least until es6) there are no classes so what you want to do in fact is to patch a final JavaScript object produced with the help of a TypeScript class. Another point I don't get is why you don't use a standard `extends` functionality. You want to create an annotation but you will still need to include this annotation in the class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get similar to the desired effect by doing something like this:

```
export function Ext(bCtor: any) 
{
    return (aCtor: any) => 
    {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(bCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            aCtor.prototype[name] = bCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    }
}
```

And apply it:

```
@Ext(B)
class A
{
    //...
}
```

Of course no more type checks as typescript does not know about this hack.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. In fact, I was asking this question because I was wondering why angular2 choose to use annotation like @Component whether than extends Component like react does.